# What do these "/jserrors/aggregate", "/metrics/aggregate", "/spa/aggregate" and "/page_action/aggregate/" mean in URL?

Tags: google-search-console, custom-error-pages

We recently had a bump in 404 pages in Google Search Console and it's giving us a list of thousands of pages suddenly discovered with these words at the end of the url:

`/jserrors/aggregate`

`/metrics/aggregate`

`/spa/aggregate`

`/page_action/aggregate`

`/page_view_event/aggregate`

`/session_trace/aggregate`

`/ajax/aggregate`

`/page_view_timing/aggregate`

I did not find any results using Google as to where do these urls come from and how can we get rid of them. I only found a bunch of other websites with indexed urls like this as well. The website is a Wordpress site if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug caused by a recent New Relic update. It's been fixed in the latest version.

https://forum.newrelic.com/s/hubtopic/aAX8W0000008eDjWAI/sessiontraceaggregate-pagevieweventaggregate-in-google-search-console
https://forum.newrelic.com/s/hubtopic/aAX8W0000008eJcWAI/thousand-of-404-errors-by-google-crawler-related-to-new-relic-cookie

Comment: Thanks, let's hope it fixes itself automatically as it seems we're loading the version 1225 already